# Handle multiple MKAnnotations selected at the same time

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm building an app that require multiple selection, callout,  with MKAnnotation, **for example, the user tap on 2 or 3 pins and he can see the three titles selected at the same time**, so the titles should not be deselected automatically

Because of the Framework that does not support multiple callout or multiple annotation selection, I searched ways to do this but without results, even in some similar posts on StackOverflow, thus...